# How to compute the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{rect}$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I am trying to compute the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{rect}$, where

$$\operatorname{rect}(t) = \begin{cases}1 &, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1\\ 0 &, \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

I used

$$\int_0^1 e^{-i\omega t}\,dt$$

and after inserting limits and substituting Euler's formula got back

$$\frac{i\cos \omega + \sin \omega}{\omega} - \frac{i}{\omega}.$$

But the answer is supposed to be

$$\frac{\sin \omega}{\omega}.$$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Is this a delta function?

Comment: What is the interval?

Comment: So I am trying to compute the Fourier transform of f(t) = 1 for 0<t<1 and 0 everywhere else. I used the integral from 0 to 1 of e^-iwt dt and got back after substituting limits and using Euler's formula (icosw + sinw/w -i/w). The answer is supposed to be sinw/w. What am I doing wrong? This is what is supposed to be above.

Comment: @z2341 Edit that into your question. If you can typeset it in MathJax ([quick reference and tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions)) to make the expressions unambiguous, that would be good, but if you can't, ASCII math will do. But you should try to make it unambiguous nevertheless; does what you wrote mean $i\cos w + \frac{\sin w}{w} - \frac{i}{w}$, or does it mean $\frac{i\cos w + \sin w}{w} - \frac{i}{w}$? As it stands now, your question is poor. With your clarification of what $f$ is and your work so far, it becomes a decent question.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. The latter. My computer won't let me type the entire question, I don't know what to do about this.

Comment: I've edited your question. Check whether I have understood everything correctly and have not introduced any typos.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thank you so much. No typos at all.

Comment: are you sure that the limits on the rect function are 0 and 1, and not symmetric like -1,1?

Comment: @danimal No it is as is.

Comment: then the answer is wrong!